# Using getdate() inside a openquery SQL to Oracle Linked Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio... Microsoft SQL Server 2012.. Management Studio version 11.0.2100.60.. I am connecting to a Oracle Server to get the data.

The error has the + before @StartDate highlighted....

My error is:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17 
Incorrect syntax near '+'.
```

My Code is:

```
Declare @cmd as varchar(8000)
Declare @StartDate varchar(30)
Declare @EndDate varchar(30)

set @StartDate = getdate() - 1
set @EndDate = getdate()


INSERT INTO dex_smallprojects..ShiftSeqData (actual) Select qty FROM OPENQUERY (jitprod, 'SELECT Count(*) AS qty FROM j_prodstep, j_prodevent, j_subject, j_subjecttype, j_prodeventset 
WHERE pre_prodstep_id = prs_id 
AND pre_subject_id = s_id 
AND s_subjecttype_id = sty_id 
AND pre_prodeventset_id = pres_id 
AND prs_key = ( ''GM:Misc:Fascia:Rear:GP12'' ) 
AND sty_keyincompany IN (''1100:GM:561MCE:Assembled:Fascia:Rear'',''1101:GM:967MCE:Assembled:Fascia:Rear'',''1102:GM:968MCE:Assembled:Fascia:Rear'') 
AND pre_tcreation BETWEEN ( To_date(''' + @StartDate @ + ''', ''MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'') ) 
AND ( To_date(''' + @EndDate @ + ''', ''MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'') )
AND pres_key = ''Default'' ')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oracle equivalent of getDate() is sysdate.  Change this:

```
AND pre_tcreation BETWEEN ( To_date(''' + @StartDate  + ''', ''MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'') ) 
AND ( To_date(''' + @EndDate  + ''', ''MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'') )
```

to this

```
and pre_tcreation between sysdate - 1 and sysdate
```

oracle will understand it.

Answer (score -1):

You had an extra @ sign where the startdate and enddate params were

Try this:

```
Declare @cmd as varchar(8000)
Declare @StartDate varchar(30)
Declare @EndDate varchar(30)

set @StartDate = getdate() - 1
set @EndDate = getdate()


INSERT INTO dex_smallprojects..ShiftSeqData (actual) Select qty FROM OPENQUERY (jitprod, 'SELECT Count(*) AS qty FROM j_prodstep, j_prodevent, j_subject, j_subjecttype, j_prodeventset 
WHERE pre_prodstep_id = prs_id 
AND pre_subject_id = s_id 
AND s_subjecttype_id = sty_id 
AND pre_prodeventset_id = pres_id 
AND prs_key = ( ''GM:Misc:Fascia:Rear:GP12'' ) 
AND sty_keyincompany IN (''1100:GM:561MCE:Assembled:Fascia:Rear'',''1101:GM:967MCE:Assembled:Fascia:Rear'',''1102:GM:968MCE:Assembled:Fascia:Rear'') 
AND pre_tcreation BETWEEN ( To_date(''' + @StartDate  + ''', ''MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'') ) 
AND ( To_date(''' + @EndDate  + ''', ''MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'') )
AND pres_key = ''Default'' ')
```